# How to implement Angular fullcalendar ui

Tags: angularjs, calendar, fullcalendar, momentjs

I'm having problems implementing `fullCalendar` for Angular. Below is my code:

```
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>

    <!-- Stylesheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fullcalendar.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">

    <!-- JS library. -->
    <script src="js/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.3.min.js"></script>

    <!-- FullCalendar -->
    <script src="js/fullcalendar/calendar.js"></script>
    <script src="js/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js"></script>
    <script src="js/fullcalendar/sv.js"></script>
    <script src="js/fullcalendar/gcal.js"></script>

    <!-- app/controller -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/schedule.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="schedule">
<div ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" ng-model="eventSources" calendar="myCalendar"> 

</body>
</html>`
```

And this is the `app/controller`:

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('schedule',['ui.calendar'])
.controller('scheduleCtrl', function($scope){

    $scope.events = [
                     {id: 1, title: 'Test', start:'2016-05-30T16:00:00', end: '2016-05-30T12:00:00'},
                     ];
    $scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];

    $scope.uiConfig = {
            calendar:{
            height: 450,
            editable: true,
            header: {
                left: 'month basicWeek basicDay agendaWeek agendaDay',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'today prev, next',
            },
            dayClick: $scope.alertEventOnClick,
            eventDrop: $scope.alertOnDrop,
            eventResize: $scope.alertOnResize
            }
    }

});
```

But I am getting below errors from `moment.min.js`:

> angular.js:13550 TypeError: Cannot read property '4' of undefined
>       at A.ca [as months] (moment.min.js:6)
>       at o. (moment.min.js:7)
>       at Object.MMMM (moment.min.js:6)
>       at U (moment.min.js:6)
>       at o.wb (moment.min.js:6)
>       at oldMomentFormat (fullcalendar.js:1549)
>       at formatSimilarChunk (fullcalendar.js:1726)
>       at formatRangeWithChunks (fullcalendar.js:1657)
>       at formatRange (fullcalendar.js:1630)
>       at FC.View.Class.extend.formatRange (fullcalendar.js:7944)

after getting the `prev` and `next` button displayed and clicked on. I figured out that it is about months in `moment.min.js`.

Answer (score 0):

**Event `start` and `end` should be a valid js date**

either

> `new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)`

or

> with `moment(2016-05-30 09:30:26)`

you can try setting dates as below

```
$scope.events = [
      {title: 'All Day Event',start: new Date(y, m, 1)},
      {title: 'Long Event',start: new Date(y, m, d - 5),end: new Date(y, m, d - 2)},
      {id: 999,title: 'Repeating Event',start: new Date(y, m, d - 3, 16, 0),allDay: false},
      {id: 999,title: 'Repeating Event',start: new Date(y, m, d + 4, 16, 0),allDay: false},
      {title: 'Birthday Party',start: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 19, 0),end: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 22, 30),allDay: false},
      {title: 'Click for Google',start: new Date(y, m, 28),end: new Date(y, m, 29),url: 'http://google.com/'}
    ];
```